React native vector icons not showing after upgrade
After a recent update to react native, i cant seem to get react-native-vector-icons to show in my android builds. I upgraded from 0.70 to 0.74.
Everyone else with this issue it seems to have something to do with this line:
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Which is in my android/app/build.gradle file correctly.
I've tried all the defaults here, cleaning out node_modules, build cache, etc.
If anyone else has run into this issue and has a solution that would great.
Also tried the steps to manually link, no luck with that either.

So as part of the upgrade i also upgraded the react-native-vector-icons lib, and within one of the recent updates the usage for ionicons has changed, it used to be that icons were preficed with ios- once removed its now working.
